can I use nav2-simple-commander in ros2 galactic
I meet trouble now.
First, I installed Ros2 foxy in ubuntu 20.04, but that nav2-simple-commander doesn't support it(foxy).
Then, I installed Ros2 Humble with Ubuntu 22.04, but I found that my lidar driver doesn't support it(humble).
So now, I check my lidar support version, I maybe install galactic.
But I don't know if nav-simple-commander support it(galactic).

Yes, it is available in ROS 2 Galactic https://github.com/ros-navigation/navigation2/tree/galactic/nav2_simple_commander
